# PHP: multiple files upload without ajax

Tags: php, file-upload, postback

I want any php script which can demonstrate me how to upload multiple files in PHP. In my application I have given a link "Add Image" & 'Remove Image', on click of "Add Image" I am adding a new upload field on the page using javascript, using which user can upload more and more images, no limit on number of images for now. On click of delete i am removing that element.

I am just not getting the concept on how to process them in the POST request in PHP. I know in HTML if we give the name of field like `myimages[]` then it will create a PHP array, but how to process this.

I don't want to use AJAX/JavaScript for uploading, want to do it with traditional POST request in PHP.

If anyone have any link or code which shows such functionality, then pleas provide it will be really helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Name file input fields as file[] in HTML, then just run a loop from 0 do count($_FILES) in PHP...

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']); $i++){
    $tmp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i];
    $name = md5(microtime());

 if(move_uploaded_file($tmp, "dir/$name.jpg")){
    echo "File '$tmp' uploaded successfully";
 }else{
    echo "Uploading '$tmp' failed";
 }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

combine this [uploading multiple files](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php) & [move_uploaded_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php)

```
<form action="file-upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  Send these files:<br />
  <input name="userfile[]" type="file" /><br />
  <input name="userfile[]" type="file" /><br />
  <input type="submit" value="Send files" />
</form>
```

---

```
$uploads_dir = '/uploads';
foreach ($_FILES["userfile"]["error"] as $key => $error) 
{
    if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) 
    {
        $tmp_name = $_FILES["userfile"]["tmp_name"][$key];
        $name = $_FILES["userfile"]["name"][$key];
        move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$uploads_dir/$name");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Uploaded files are not in the POST array, they are in the FILES array.
http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php

The files are uploaded to a temp area with "safe" names. The array will contain the name of the file and the tmp file. You can then move them to where you want.

Answer (score 1):

I've implemented something similar in the past as follows:

1. Have a hidden JavaScript form variable (e.g.: "numuploads") that stores the number of file inputs currently in the form. This will need to be incremented/decremented when you add/remove an input on the front end.
2. Name each of the inputs on the front end using a pattern such as "upload_X", where X is the next in the sequence. (Effectively the same as the counter above -1.)
3. On the PHP landing page, simply scan the [$_FILES superglobal](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php), looking for each "upload_X" where X is zero thru numuploads - 1.

You can then carry out the required logic for each of the uploaded files, other form elements, etc.

Comment: There is one issue I see, let's say user added u1, u2, u3 then he deleted u2, now on page we have u1 and u3. Do you have any similar scrpit concept in js/jquery which I can use to address this issue?